# How to implement Tagging using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

I have 2 columns in my database table.

```
ID     Tags
1      tag1,tag2
2      tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6
```

Now I want to print the tags with ID. Like:

```
ID: 1
#tag1 #tag2


ID: 2
#tag3 #tag4 #tag5 #tag6
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Don't use comma-separated lists in a database column. Use a many-to-many relationship table.

Answer (score 1):

I think if i understand what you need then i think this is what you need

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
$results = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from tags");
if (mysqli_error($conn)) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn); 
} else {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($conn) > 0) {
        while($result = mysqi_fetch_array($results)) {
            $tags = explode(',', $result['Tags']);
            ?>
                <label>ID: <?php echo $result['ID']; ?></label><br />
                <label><?php echo implode(' #', $tags); ?>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
            <label>There is no result</label>
        <?php   
    }
}
```